# See where javascript promise was invoked from debugger?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm trying to figure out how some code works and I put a breakpoint in some Promise implementation code. How can I see who invoked the promise? For example I'm stopped in the debugger here:

```
 resolve(data);
```

I tried stepping through this code to see where the code that will execute once resolved but got stuck. Is there any way to figure out where the resolve is going?

(Btw, I'm using Ember and I think RSVP promise)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.trace()` to get the caller of the function. You can also utilize `console.profile()` and `console.profileEnd()` to profile specific code, where the results can be viewed at the browser Dev Tools or Developer Tools JavaScript Profiler.

```js
const fn = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(123)
    console.trace();
  })
}

// console.profile("promise");
fn();
// console.profileEnd("profile");
/*
js:16 console.trace
resolve @ js:16
fn @ js:14
(anonymous) @ js:20
*/
```

Comment: Your example isn't even asynchronous. It's obvious that a trace would work there.

Comment: @Bergi Was not certain about the exact placement of `console.profleEnd()`, included and commented out the calls for OP for further options to consider.

Comment: @Bergi If that is what you mean by "Your example isn't even asynchronous", else not sure what you are referring to.